# how to compiler union/map using gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to port code compiled with ifort to gfortran. When I update gfortran to version 6 and compile the code with UNION/MAP, there is an error:

```
Unexpected UNION statement at (1).
```

How can I fix this?

```
  union
    map
    integer*4 :: ndim_par=0           
    integer*4 :: ndim_par_actual=0    

  end map
  map
    integer*4 :: mamb          
    integer*4 :: mobs         
  end map
end union
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with option `-fdec-structure`?  This may not work in your case, or require a later version of gfortran.  You may also see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14733238/3157076).

Comment: You need at least version 7 or newer to compiler the code.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News#GCC7

Comment: i update to version 8, use -fdec-structure , but it doesnot work

Comment: We really need the details from you. What kind of errors do you get? See [ask]. It is also good to tske the [tour].

Comment: the compiler show: Error: Unexpected UNION statement at (1

Comment: Have you followed @Vladimir's advice about asking questions here?  What is the **complete** minimum example code you are trying to compile?  The code in your initial post is an incomplete fragment!

Comment: The code shown is not compilable. In the absence of context, it's easy to believe that the error is caused by the `union` statement occurring in the wrong place in a Fortran program.  Fortran is very specific about the ordering of statements; in a nutshell all declarations must precede any executable statements.

Comment: A fellow named Fritz added that UNION/MAP into gfortran a coupled of years ago.

Comment: OP's code won't compile because it isn't wrapped in a DEC `STRUCTURE` ... `END STRUCTURE` construct.